# Take data from two tables and show in one row without duplicates with a where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to take the data from two tables and output them in one row . 
output will have two columns "to" and "from" where the condition is "from" will be having data from second table where type is true and "to" column will have data from second table where type is false  . FK_ID in second table is linked to ID on the first table . Please help with the query.

I was trying to do with inner joins and union was not able to make it work . Thanks in advance .

TABLE 1

```
ID | PATH|
 1 | ABC |
 2 | EFG |
```

TABLE 2

```
ID | FK_ID | NUMBER | TYPE
20 | 1     | 123    | TRUE  
21 | 1     | 456    | FALSE  
28 | 2     | 888    | FALSE  
29 | 2     | 939    | TRUE
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
ID |  PATH | TO  | FROM
1  |  ABC  | 456 | 123
2  |  EFG  | 888 | 939
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation with pivoting logic to identify the "to" and "from" components of each path:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.PATH,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.TYPE = 'FALSE' THEN t2.NUMBER END) AS "TO",
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.TYPE = 'TRUE'  THEN t2.NUMBER END) AS "FROM"
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.FK_ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.PATH
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue, you might find a `lateral join` to be faster:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT SUM(T2.NUMBER) FILTER (WHERE NOT t2.TYPE) as num_to,
             SUM(T2.NUMBER) FILTER (WHERE t2.TYPE) as num_from             
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t1.ID = t2.FK_ID
     ) t2
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

This avoids the outer `GROUP BY` and probably the sorting as well (assuming that `ID` is the primary key).

It also assumes that `TYPE` is a Postgres boolean type.  If not, use string comparisons for the `WHERE` clauses.